# Javascript AngularJS function doesnt run when expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code in my angularjs

```
 $scope.uploadImage = function(imageURI, fileName) {

    upload(imageURI, fileName)
    console.log("AFTER CALL upload");


    function upload(imageURI, fileName) {

       $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        console.log(FileTransfer);
      });

      console.log("in upload to s3")
      var deferred = $q.defer(),
        options = new FileUploadOptions();
        console.log("before options")
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileName;
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.params = {
            "key": fileName,
            "AWSAccessKeyId": awsKey,
            "acl": acl,
            "policy": policyBase64,
            "signature": signature,
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
        };

        console.log(s3URI)
        console.log(imageURI)

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI,
          function (e) {
            console.log("done done")
            //push url here 
            // console.log(s3URI)
            // console.log(fileName)
            // $scope.finalimagelist.push(s3URI+fileName);
            // console.log($scope.finalimagelist)
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
            //   deferred.resolve(e); 
            //   console.log("IN upload");

          },
          function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
          }, 
        options);
            console.log("ON upload");
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.finalimagelist));
            return deferred.promise;

  }
}
```

The problem with this code is that these

```
console.log("ON upload");
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.finalimagelist));
return deferred.promise;
```

get called before `ft.Upload()` executes. I would expect for `ft.Upload()` to execute first before the rest continues.

What am i doing wrong here?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: what `ft.upload` returns ?

Comment: just the status response from the upload.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the promise object to resolve. Simple plunkr example using setTimeout to mock the file transfer: http://plnkr.co/edit/vVkiI3KjeWgiUvCubUmQ

```
 upload(imageURI, fileName).then(function(result){
     console.log("AFTER CALL upload");
 });
```

also resolve the promise here:

```
function (e) {
            console.log("done done")
            //push url here 
            // console.log(s3URI)
            // console.log(fileName)
            // $scope.finalimagelist.push(s3URI+fileName);
            // console.log($scope.finalimagelist)
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
            //   deferred.resolve(e); 
            //   console.log("IN upload");
            deferred.resolve();
          },
```

So I noticed you weren't trying to wait for the promise in the first place. You were just executing code in the function that returns the promise. If you want that code to execute AFTER ft.upload, you need to put it in the callback.

```
$scope.uploadImage = function(imageURI, fileName) {

    upload(imageURI, fileName)
    console.log("AFTER CALL upload");


    function upload(imageURI, fileName) {

       $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        console.log(FileTransfer);
      });

      console.log("in upload to s3")
      var deferred = $q.defer(),
        options = new FileUploadOptions();
        console.log("before options")
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = fileName;
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.params = {
            "key": fileName,
            "AWSAccessKeyId": awsKey,
            "acl": acl,
            "policy": policyBase64,
            "signature": signature,
            "Content-Type": "image/jpeg"
        };

        console.log(s3URI)
        console.log(imageURI)

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI,
          function (e) {
            console.log("done done")
            //push url here 
            // console.log(s3URI)
            // console.log(fileName)
            // $scope.finalimagelist.push(s3URI+fileName);
            // console.log($scope.finalimagelist)
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
            //   deferred.resolve(e); 
            //   console.log("IN upload");

            //PUT THIS STUFF HERE
            console.log("ON upload");
            console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.finalimagelist));
            deferred.resolve();
          },
          function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
          }, 
        options);

            return deferred.promise;

  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice you weren't resolving the promise anywhere. I assume this is the success function (the function that runs after the async process is complete)

Comment: Edited again, the stuff you are expecting to wait for ft.upload to happen should be in the callback. Otherwise the code will start ft.upload then keep going by executing your console.logs. Also you should return the promise where it is, it will not resolve until you call deferred.resolve(). To wait for ft.upload to be done you either need to put code in your callback or put it in the then function of the promise object like in my first suggestion

Comment: thnks for your help. i appreciate the time and the effort but it still doesnt work.

Comment: I added a plunkr showing everything excecuting in the order I think you want.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, if you are getting response you can check it in if condition and then run `"ON Upload"` lines,

#### Example code

```
var ftUpload = ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI,
          function (e) {
            console.log("done done")
            //push url here 
            // console.log(s3URI)
            // console.log(fileName)
            // $scope.finalimagelist.push(s3URI+fileName);
            // console.log($scope.finalimagelist)
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
            //   deferred.resolve(e); 
            //   console.log("IN upload");

          },
          function (e) {
            deferred.reject(e);
          }, 
        options);

if ( ftUpload == YOUR_STATUS_CODE ) {
       console.log("ON upload");
       console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.finalimagelist));
       return deferred.promise;
}
```

Change condition according to your code.

Comment: i have no clue but it always runs the if(ftUpload == YOUR_STATUS_CODE) code before it runs the var ftUpload = ft.upload(imageURI, s3URI) code